# jQuery $.post doesn't pass what button were pressed

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit, .post

Recently I've stuck with a problem where $.post does not send information about button which were pressed.
I.e. we have a form with two buttons.

```
<form method="post"  action="/home/index">

  <input type='hidden' name='data1' value='value1' />

  <button name="button1" type="submit">First</button>
  <button name="button2" type="submit">Second</button>

</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formId').submit(function () {
        var f = $(this);
        var action = f.attr("action");
        var serf = f.serialize();
        $.post(action, serf,
        //onreturn
          function (data) {
                //do something here on success
              },
              'json'
          );
        return false;
      });
});
```

Without ajax form is posted as following if user pressed First button: **data1=value1&button1**

But when I use $.post posted form does not contain any information about button: **data1=value1**

jQuery 1.6.1

The behavior depends on that which button were pressed.
Any help or workaround would be appriciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're stopping the browser's default behavior, which is what supplies the button value, you'll have to capture what button was pressed, and add that information to the data you're posting (your `serf` data). Probably the most reliable way would be to hook the `click` event on the buttons as well as the `submit` event of the form, and route them all to a central function that does the ajax submission with (or without) a button value (without in the case of a form submitted another way, rather than by pressing one of those buttons).

Something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function submitTheForm(f, button) {
        var action = f.attr("action");
        var serf = f.serialize();
        if (button && button.name) {
            serf += "&" + encodeURIComponent(button.name);
            if (button.value) {
                serf += "=" + encodeURIComponent(button.value);
            }
        }
        $.post(action, serf,
        //onreturn
          function (data) {
                //do something here on success
          },
          'json'
        );
    }
    $('#formId').submit(function () {
        submitTheForm($(this));
        return false;
    });
    $("#formId :submit").click(function() {
        submitTheForm($(this).closest('form'), this);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I was more focused on the buttons than on what he was actually doing ;) +1

Comment: @Starx: Forms are normally sent URI-encoded. [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) correctly encodes the component parts of a URI-encoded string. So for instance, if the button had the value "Send Form", `encodeURIComponent` returns "Send%20Form" since in URI-encoding, a space must be encoded. Both the name and the value of a name/value pair must be encoded, although you see a lot of people missing out encoding the names (it's usually okay, if you pick names that aren't changed by encoding).

Comment: I also thought about manual adding parameters but it looks a bit cluncky. Thank you!

Comment: @Cheburek: No worries. It only adds a couple of lines, and if you really wanted to, you could always wrap it up in a utility function / plug-in for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is suppose to be happening. But anyways, you could something like this too.

```
$("#formid").children("input[type="submit"]").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    post(name);
    return false;
});
function post(buttnname) {
    var action = $("#formid").attr("action");
    var serf = $("#formid").serialize()+"&button="+buttname;
    $.post(action, serf,
    //onreturn
        function (data) {
            //do something here on success
          },
          'json'
        );
}
```